# In what sense does integration “raise the power by 1”

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am working on a problem that requires me to compare the value of a particular, but generically defined function, with the definite integral of that function.

Naturally, if the function is a polynomial then I can compute the definite integral, and the result is explicitly a polynomial of degree 1 higher than the original function.

I am wondering in what precise sense (if any) one can say this in general. That is, that integrating raises the degree by 1. Perhaps using Taylor series or big-$O$ notation.

To be concrete, I want to compare $f(x^p)$ with $$\int_x^1 f(t^p) dt $$ as $p$ gets large, where $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ say.

Comment: you don't mean "genetically", you mean "generically" :P

Comment: Indeed I don’t. Thanks for picking it up!

Comment: Integration term by term of taylor series is indeed allowed, see https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf since Taylor series converge locally uniformly